# How to iterate unusual html element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using CodeRay to generate html code and almost all text elements wrapped in `span` but some of them didn't. In the example you can see that `primary_key_prefix_type` doesn't wrap in at all.

```
<span class="no">1172</span><span class="r">case</span> primary_key_prefix_type
<span class="no">1173</span><span class="r">when</span> <span class="sy">:table_name</span>
```

But I need to iterate through all elements by using `next()` and `prev()` functions from jQuery.
Therefore I'm missing the `primary_key_prefix_type` because it's not an element for jQuery. How to 'see' all elements? Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to do with them?

Comment: If you have to parse highlighted sourcecode something else is wrong. Why can't you access a raw version?

Comment: I want to highlight the specific element, firstly i search the line number by <span class="no">1173</span> and then looking for the element in that line, that's why just searching it as raw isn't so convenient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) which includes text nodes as well.

```
$("#test").contents().each(function() { 
    //do something with each node
});
```

**[Example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/zhNG4/)**

Update
[`.nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.nextSibling) will get the next element regardless if it is an element or a text node.

```
$(".r")[0].nextSibling;
```

**[Example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/zhNG4/3/)**

Comment: Is it possible just having the jQuery element and then get the next text node? Iterating the whole content by contents function isn't convenient for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.contents()` which will select all elements AND textnodes.

```
$('#container').contents().each(function() {
   if (this.nodeType == 3 || this.tagName == 'SPAN')
   {
       var text = $(this).text();
       // Don't act on empty text i.e. just spaces/tabs
       if (!text.match(/^[\s\t]*$/))
       {
          alert(text);  
       }
   }
});
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/Zrb7F/3/